# Dropbox does not automatically upload post-processed photos

Tags: dropbox

I copied many photos from my Nikon SLR to my Android, and edited a few with Photo Editor and Little photo. Some uploaded successfully using dropbox Camera Upload facility.

This weekend, it stopped automatically uploading photos that I edited using these apps.

I re installed dropbox, tried disabling then enabling automatic upload, I tried moving the files to Camera directory, but they won't automatically upload. Taking a normal picture using camera phone automatically upload photos just fine.

Why aren't my word photos no longer being automatically uploaded any more? How can I enable it again?

Comment: Does "Photo Editor" replace the original file in your dropbox, or save the edited file in your dropbox? In other words the edited file is being saved back to your dropbox and not some other folder (outside of dropbox) on your SD card?

Comment: The photos are edited on my phone, and are renamed, as well as placed in a separate directory, beneath the /DCIM directory. Dropbox was previously able to upload the original photo, and the subsequently edited photo.

Comment: Are you moving these files to the "Camera Uploads" directory within dropbox? Dropbox does not normally sync directories beneath /DCIM (I assume this is on your SD card, ie. outside of dropbox) such as "/DCIM/Camera", unless you are perhaps using a third party app such as Dropsync? What is the "automatic upload" feature in dropbox that you can enable/disable? The only related feature I see in Settings is "Turn off Camera Upload" - but this does not relate to the automatic uploading of files within your dropbox.